# How can I make a 100% stacked chart with nvd3?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I looked at nvd3 stacked charts, and does anyone know how can I make a 100% stacked chart with nvd3?

For example, a chart like this: https://www.syncfusion.com/content/en-US/Products/Images/wpf/chart/wpf-chart-ColumnStacked100.jpg

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't supported in NVD3.

Answer (score 2):

I used the multibar chart and then transformed the data to simulate a 100% stacked bar chart. I had to add each of the bar's values and then divide value in the bar by the total value of the bar.

Comment: I would love some more specific details or an example!