# How to achieve 100% stacked bar chart in nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have created a multibar chart using nvd3 charts using `var chart1 = nv.models.multiBarChart();`

I searched a lot, but couldn't able to find how to  implement 100% stacked bar chart in nvd3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a 100% stacked chart with nvd3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157147/how-can-i-make-a-100-stacked-chart-with-nvd3)